# Verify all validation message

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to verify all validation message one by one on single page as like registration form using selenium web-driver with java in Hybrid framework

Comment: Questions asking for "homework" help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: You need to add your code trials, html and explain what is the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:
i) create generic java methods for all the validations you want to perform on a web page by passing the object as a parameter along with the property you want to work with.

Then call these validations in your page object test class.